# Error statment creation N tables DBUnit + HsqlDb (v. 2.3.2)

Tags: testing, jdbc, hsqldb, dbunit

I'm using `DBUnit` + `hsqlDB` for database unit testing. Until now, we used `hsqldb` version 1.8.0.10.

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.0.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

We've some scripts to create the database schema (which create multiple tables). We load + execute these scripts through [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Something basicaly like that:

```
   @Test
   public void testMultipleTablesError() throws Exception {
      IDatabaseTester databaseTester = new JdbcDatabaseTester("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test");
      Connection connection = databaseTester.getConnection().getConnection();
      try {
         String scriptDDL = "CREATE TABLE TABLE_A(A  VARCHAR(10)); CREATE TABLE TABLE_B(B  VARCHAR(10))";
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(scriptDDL);
         preparedStatement.execute();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         try {
            connection.close();
         } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
```

This works fine with 1.8.0.10. But if we change to `hsqldb` version `2.3.2` we get an exception when prepare the statment:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: palabra no esperado: CREATE
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
```

If we change the script to create only one table, it works fine in both version:

```
String scriptDDL = "CREATE TABLE TABLE_A(A  VARCHAR(10))";
```

Anyone knows if the syntax for create many tables has changed between versions?

Thanks for the help in advance

*EDIT*: `DBUnit` version:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CREATE TABLE statements that were valid with HSQLDB 1.8.0 are still valid. The change relates to the `prepareStatement()` method and it now accepts only single SQL statements. You can still use `createStatement()` and `Statement.execute(script)` with multiple SQL statements.

Comment: Many thanks! I took for granted that the problem was the hsqldb version, my mistake! I've changed the statement as you say and it works fine. Thanks.